# CSS display: inline; float: left, but div blocks don't stay one close to the other

Tags: css, css-float, inline

Does anyone know how to make Block 3 not to go under Block2.
I would like Block3 to show under Block 1, and Block 4 then would go on the right of Block 3.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html><head>   
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252"> <!-- don't use closing slash in meta tag, it breaks HTML4.01 transitional -->
   <title>Test</title>

   <style type="text/css">      
      /* in the style below the width and border and margin must not be modified */
      div.float_box {display: inline; float: left; width: 100px; border: 1px solid #ff0000; margin: 10px;}
      p.clear {clear: both; height: 0px;}
   </style>

</head><body>

   <!-- This outside div must not be touched or modified -->
   <div style="width: 300px; padding: 10px; border: 1px dashed #cccccc;">
      <!-- Blocks' height must not be modified by adding contents or setting styles -->
      <div class="float_box">Block 1<br><br><br><br><br></div>
      <div class="float_box">Block 2<br><br></div>
      <div class="float_box">Block 3<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br></div>
      <div class="float_box">Block 4<br><br></div>
      <p class="clear"></p>
   </div>   

</body></html>
```

Thanks!

This obviously is only an example, but **I need a solution that works idipendently from the length of the blocks, and indipendently from the number of the blocks.**
Someone suggested to use "clear: both", on block 3, but this would solve only this particular case, what if I had another block 5 of the same height or longer than block 3 and after another block 6, the problem would rise up again and to fix it I would have to set manually the clear both on block 5. I need a general solution, because I don't know in advance length and number of blocks (coz they are dynamically generated from a DB).

I would like to see all my blocks be displaied one close to the other (separated simply by the margin 10xp I set) while fitting into the outside div 300px box. **Moreover the otside div box of 300px could expand and blocks inside should reposition themeselves** adapting to the new size (for example by fitting into three/four columns).

Comment: You should have been more specific in the first place that you were dynamically generating the blocks and that the number of blocks could vary.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to add another class ("clear"?) to the Block 3 div, with a definition of:

```
div.clear { clear:both; }
```

Of course, CSS doesn't always behave as you initially expect...

Comment: But this would solve the issue only in this particular case, I need a general purpose solution.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the block3 class to this (added clear:left;) and that gives you the result you were looking for.

```
div.block3 {display: inline; float: left; width: 100px; border: 1px solid #ff0000; margin: 10px; clear:left;}
```

EDIT:
Since this is now known to be a dynamically generated scenario due to clarification of the question the solution is to count up the total number of blocks that will need to be generated at run time and then add the clear attribute where appropriate.  If you can't find out how many boxes you will have before you generate the HTML there is no way you can make the layout work.

For instance if you have five blocks then you would have to add clear attributes to boxes 3 and 5 to make sure they clear their left hand neighbors (in the case of a two column solution).

If the box could expand and change to a three or four column layout then you have other issues.  You really can't have both a fixed layout and an expandable layout in the case where you trying to position columns.

Comment: But this would solve the issue only in this particular case, I need a general purpose solution